# Configure routing for multiple USB modems linux

Tags: iptables, routing, linux-networking

i am trying to create a custom proxy server. I have a Rasp Pi box with 2 USB LTE modems and LAN cable connected to it. I am trying to get them working together with squid proxy so that i could send traffic to specific the modem's NIC depending on the internal ip, also i need to be able to address modem's admin dashboard to be able to reset it programmiracly if it stops working properly. So, when i connect modem alone to the rasp box i see that admin dashboard has default gateway`s address - 192.168.0.1, so i figured i could get going with this setup:

```
$: cat /etc/network/interfaces
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.1.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0

allow-hotplug eth2
iface eth2 inet static
    address 192.168.2.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0

$: ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1 table rteth1
$: ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth1 table rteth1
$: ip route add 10.0.0.0/24 dev eth0 src 10.0.0.1 table rteth1
$: ip rule add from 192.168.1.0/24 table rteth1
$: ip rule add to 192.168.1.0/24 table rteth1
$: iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
$: iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -m ttl --ttl-gt 50 -o eth1 -j TTL --ttl-set 65
```

The same setup for 192.168.2.0/24 network. When i configure the network this way and try to request admin dashboard(192.168.1.1) - i get this error:

```
$: curl 192.168.1.1
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.1.1 port 80: No route to host
```

When i try to setup it with:
$: ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth1 table rteth1

I get: `RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable`

How can i properly set up such network?

Comment: Did you just make a typo?

Comment: What do you mean? English is not my native language, sorry for errors if any.

Comment: You said you typed: `ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth1 table rteth1`. But you never used that IP address or network anywhere else in your whole setup.

Comment: Yes, I just thought that if I specify gateway of the modem it would work, the 192.168.0.1 is the gateway of the modem if I connect it through its dhcp

Comment: But you have not given your network interface an IP address in that network! It is in a different network.

Comment: How can I do that? Give it up in that network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out myself. First, i needed to set NIC ip address to the address from USB modem's subnet - ip 192.168.1.1 will not work, so:

```
$: cat /etc/network/interfaces
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.0.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0

allow-hotplug eth2
iface eth2 inet static
    address 192.168.0.101
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Second, i was missing the local rule to translate gateway ip address from one subnet to other, here is how it should used to be:

```
# Setup routing for NIC
$: ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1 table rteth1
$: ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth1 table rteth1
$: ip route add 10.0.0.0/24 dev eth0 src 10.0.0.1 table rteth1
$: ip rule add from 192.168.1.0/24 table rteth1
$: ip rule add to 192.168.1.0/24 table rteth1
# Substitute sender ip addres by router ip address to recive back package
$: iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
# Set up local routing, when requesting ip localy Substitute it
$: iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o eth1 -p tcp -d 192.168.1.1 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.1
# execute changes
ip route flush cache
```

The same setup is for eth2 with 192.168.2.0/24 network and cetera. With this setup i can call specific modem's dashboard by making request curl 192.168.1/2.1
I did not knew before about very handy command: tcpdump, with its help i have managed to figure out the problem:

```
$: tcpdump -i eth1
$: 05:28:30.685038 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.1 tell 192.168.0.100, length 28
$: 05:28:31.732788 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.1 tell 192.168.0.100, length 28
$: 05:28:32.772795 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.1 tell 192.168.0.100, length 28
$: 05:28:33.813216 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.1 tell 192.168.0.100, length 28
```